# Is the word "viceroy" used anywhere?

Tags: word-usage

I've heard this word a few times but can't really understand if it's really in use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by 'in use'.

A viceroy is an official who rules a country or colony in the name of the King (or Queen) of the territory. Therefore, with the decline in monarchies across the world comes a decline in viceroys.

The title is almost never officially used nowadays (though the Governor-General of the Commonwealth of Australia and the Lieutenant governor of Canada still officially hold the title 'viceroy'), but the the term is still commonly encountered when referencing history and historical fiction.

Comment: Yeh. That's exactly what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 1):

It depends in what sense you mean "used".

It is the name of a butterfly which is similar to the Monarch

[image]

It is also used in the names of some restaurants and corporations worldwide.

Comment: I've heard it in news a few times and in political discussions.